# Image with click map inside a container with scroll-x: auto not working in iOS & Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, imagemap

We have a wide image (a colour palette) that doesn't fit on mobile, so we placed the image in a container with horizontal scroll bar. It works everywhere except for iOS and Safari. When the user starts dragging from a clickable area of the image using these browsers, the container doesn't scroll. However, when the user starts dragging from a non clickable area, the container scrolls properly. If I remove the map completely, the container scrolls fine as well.

Is there a workaround for this bug? Or we need to replace the implementation with SVG or absolutely positioned elements on top of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with absolutely positioned divs on top of the image and it works great.